# Refreshing items as the user scrolls down in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, pagination, swiperefreshlayout

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout on my RecyclerView, I want the items to refresh as the user scrolls down instead of just pulling down from the top every time. I need something like Instagram or facebook that the posts load as the user is scrolling down. So that the user doesn't have to keep coming up again and again to refresh and load more posts

Here is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bar">

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bar"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_posts"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
//POSTS
private RecyclerView recyclerViewPosts;
private PostAdapter postAdapter;
private List<Post> postLists;
private List<String> followingList;
private Context mContext;
private static final int TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_LOAD = 5;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private int currentPage = 1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

//POSTS
recyclerViewPosts = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_posts);
recyclerViewPosts.setHasFixedSize(true);
final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerViewPosts.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
postLists = new ArrayList<>();
postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postLists);
recyclerViewPosts.setAdapter(postAdapter);
swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
checkFollowing();
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    currentPage++;
    postLists.clear();
    readPosts();
    }
    });
    return view;
    }
private void readPosts() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    Query postQuery = reference.limitToLast(currentPage * TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
    postQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    postLists.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    postLists.add(post);
    }
    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: hey. Do you have a lot of items? and you want to display the items ten to ten for example??? with user scroll?

Comment: @hamidkeyhani yes thats exactly what I want...and yeah I have a lot of images and they keep on increasing as more posts are coming

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [`Paging Library`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) from Android. It is design for it and you have a nice tutorial for it [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#0). It might be a bit of work but it is worth it.

Comment: okay I will take a look at it, thanks...do you think it will work with Firebase? @Biscuit